# What's the difference between these two schemes code (macro)

Tags: macros, scheme

I try to understand by playing around with some code I found in [MIT-Scheme documentation](http://web.mit.edu/scheme_v9.0.1/doc/mit-scheme-ref/SC-Transformer-Definition.html). 
one piece of code about sc-macro-transformer:

```
(define-syntax let1
        (sc-macro-transformer
         (lambda (form env)
           (let ((id (cadr form))
                 (init (caddr form))
                 (exp (cadddr form)))
             `((lambda (,id)
                 ,(make-syntactic-closure env (list id) exp))
               ,(make-syntactic-closure env '() init))))))

  ;(let1 a 1 (+ a 1))
  ;Value: 2
```

but I wonder if can I take the part of "**make-syntactic-closure**" from `lambda ... to the body of "let.." and the program becomes :

```
(define-syntax let1-error
    (sc-macro-transformer        
      (lambda (form env)
         (let ((id  (cadr form))
              (init (make-syntactic-closure env '() (caddr form)))
              (exp (make-syntactic-closure env '(id) (cadddr form))))
  ;; (pp `(id:,id))
  ;; (pp `(init:, init))
  ;; (pp `(exp:, exp))
   `((lambda (,id)
    ,exp) 
 ,init)))))
;(let1-error a 1 (+ a 1))
;Unbound variable: a
```

Can someone told me why that these two program is different?

Comment: This is just a guess without running MIT-scheme, but in lifting the code you translated (list id) to '(id), which is not the same thing. (list id) creates a new list with the symbol bound by the identifier id, i.e. (cadr form), every time the macro is expanded. However, '(id) is a literal list of the symbol "id". Thus let1 expands (list id) to '(a) while let1-error expands it to '(id). You should be able to check this with a macro expansion procedure, though I don't know what that is for MIT-scheme specifically.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is likely with:

```
(make-syntactic-closure env '(id) (cadddr form)))
```

Compare that to the previous version.

You probably want that to be `(list id)` instead.